# Shortest line forced to field attribute

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I have a layer with point geometry with a field `STREETCODE` that represents the entry number of each house. On the other hand, I have, a layer with line geometry with the field `STREETCODE`, representing the centerline axis of each street.

My objective is to use an expression to obtain a graphical representation to identify to which street axis each house entrance belongs.

For the demonstration I use a layer of line symbols from the Geometry Generator on my points layer:

```
shortest_line($geometry,aggregate('LINESTREETS','collect',$geometry))
```

When I test the expression it works fine for most cases. However, for some cases it would be necessary to force it to draw the shortest_line according to the `STREETCODE = STREETCODE`.

[image: shortest lines issues on QGIS canvas]

Comment: Something like : `shortest_line($geometry, aggregate('LINESTREETS', 'collect', $geometry, "STREETCODE" = attribute(@parent, 'STREETCODE')))` ?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved from J. Monticolo comment**:

```
shortest_line($geometry, aggregate('LINESTREETS', 'collect', $geometry, "STREETCODE" = attribute(@parent, 'STREETCODE')))
```